# Planck.js (rewritten of Box2D.js) - 8 direction box movement

Tags: javascript, box2d

I have a box in Planck.js. I want to move this box with some keys. How can I do that? My code:

```
planck.testbed("boxworld", function(testbed) {
  var pl = planck,
    Vec2 = pl.Vec2;
  var world = new pl.World(Vec2(0, 0));

  //Box

  var box = world
    .createDynamicBody(Vec2(0.0, 10.0))
    .createFixture(pl.Box(0.5, 0.5), 20.0);
  box.render = { fill: "#FA8072", stroke: "black" };

  return world;
});
```

[image: top down 8 direction movement]

Answer (score 0):

You could set velocity for the box, [apply force](https://piqnt.com/planck.js/ApplyForce) or directly [change location](https://piqnt.com/planck.js/PolyCollision).